# Dismiss job offer disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I noticed the dismiss button disappeared from the job offers next to the question list.

[image]

Checking the code, I see there's a space missing between `<a` and `class`, and probably another problem related to this.

`<aclass="clc-dismiss"data-clc-click="https: clc.stackoverflow.com="" click?an="4_zxu8FjhuoVD864_mBXJkYGBgYBBhBYt4qFITtGg4HhBBAzsDAwNIBEGUEKmKRlRBgYqkUg4geUre9bMtw6aiftycHEIFLDDBJlaY5nX2Zp893TnuHA_DUv7nC3yH1dAQA&amp;cr=228372&amp;ct=-1&amp;sig=gFB2jHKP8aD8jQ&quot;data-clc-meta-target=&quot;-1&quot;"><span class="clc-tooltip above-left">dismiss this job</span></aclass="clc-dismiss"data-clc-click="https:>`

Splitting the tag and the attribute allowed me to click (it wouldn't appear at first, but only on hover), but the click didn't work later, at took me to `https://%20clc.stackoverflow.com%3D/` instead of dismissing the offer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for spotting this! We're working on a fix asap!

Comment: Anytime @HoriaComan!

Comment: Should be fixed! Though it might take a small while before it's globally visible, depending on how it gets cached by folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fixed.

It was the weirdest html generation error. I had to remove a newline and things were fixed. I'll have to consult with colleagues on what could have went wrong, because both the original and the new code looked alright.

Thanks for taking the time to point it out @Korcholis.

Comment: Working again, perfect! My pleasure to help =)